# Mining statistics dashboard

Tags: mining-pools, statistics

I am searching for a public mining statistics dashboard that lets you see per BTC address/transaction how much was mined, when, and a way of making sure that those Bitcoins indeed come from a miner. It is necessary for tax purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Any block explorer should do, if the address contains coinbase inputs (not to be confused with the company) then there's your proof of mined coins.

Read more about what coinbase transactions are here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Coinbase

https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/block_chain.html